# Quarkus Install Error [jbang] [ERROR] java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException

Tags: quarkus

I am following the Getting Started Guide from the Quarkus site to try out Quarkus. But, when I execute this curl command

`curl -Ls https://sh.jbang.dev | bash -s - app install --fresh --force quarkus@quarkusio`

the following error is displayed.

`[jbang] [ERROR] java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1`

Running quarkus install on Mac (Intel) running Monterey OS and here's my java info:

```
java --version
java 11.0.6 2020-01-14 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.6+8-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.6+8-LTS, mixed mode)

whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java

which java
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.6.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

Can somebody please let me know what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used SDKMAN! to install Quarkus and that seemed to work.